# Laravel Eloquent: How to add where condition from the with function model relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Anyone can help me? How to add where condition from the with function model relation.

I tried  `->where('driver.group_id',$group_id)` but it does not work. please look my code below.

```
public function getDriversDailyEarnings()
    {
        $group_id = Auth::user()->group->id;
        $today = Carbon::today();

        $data = DailyEarnings::with(['payout_cost',
        'status:id,name',
        'driver' => function ($query) {
            $query->with('user');
        }])
        ->where('driver.group_id',$group_id)
        ->whereDate('created_at', $today)
        ->get();

        return response()->json($data, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Haven't tested it yet.

```
DailyEarnings::with([
      'payout_cost', 
      'status:id,name'
      'driver' => function($query) {
         $query->where('group_id', auth()->user()->group->id)->with('user');
      }
   ])
   ->whereHas('driver', function($query) {
      $query->where('group_id', auth()->user()->group->id);
   })
   ->whereDate('created_at', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
   ->get();
```

Comment: This is work but i updated it to this.
```->whereHas('driver', function($query) use ($group_id){
            $query->where('group_id', $group_id);
         })```.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

To pass other clauses to a relation, just use it inside an array, where the key and the name of the relation and the value is a function that receives an instance of the query, something like this:

```
public function getDriversDailyEarnings()
{
    $data = DailyEarnings::with([
        'payout_cost' => function ($myWithQuery) {
            $myWithQuery->where('column-of-relation-here', 'value-here')
                ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%Steve%');;
         }
    ])->get();

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
  //        ->where('driver.group_id',$group_id)
            ->whereHas('driver', fn($qry) => $qry->where('group_id', $group_id)) // if group_id a field on driver
```

Comment: Wow this is nice and short. it also works.. but my editor:VS code detects error in this code ```fn($qry) => $qry->```.