# Optimize laravel code that populates a searchable textfield

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have the following code that is working fine, I am trying to fetch about 50,000 cities in a searchable textfield using laravel but it takes alot of time and browser becoming inactive. How can I optimize so that it is fast.

```
public function searchCity()
{
    $country = Country::with('states.cities')->find(231);

    if ($country) {
        $cities = $country->states->flatMap->cities->pluck('name')->toArray();;
        return $cities;
    } else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Country not found'], 404);
    }

}
```

and the ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/searchcity",
        success: function (response) {
          townsTags = response;
          startAutocomplete(townsTags, "#search_towns");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Do you need to dump all 50k cities in one page? If not, you may need to use pagination for this result.

Comment: Thanks for response, it is a search i dont want to display all, in fact i can fetch like the first 10 depending on what the user is typing

Comment: Since you want only 10 on the result, you may need to use a function when you call `Country::with('states.cities')->find(231);` something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66165718

Comment: Basically, you want to limit the data returned from your `with('states.cities')` eagerLoading method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you perform your search on the server side?

You could send the item you're searching as query params:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/searchcity",
    data: { query: search },
    success: function (response) {
        townsTags = response;
        startAutocomplete(townsTags, "#search_towns");
    }
});
```

And then search for specific result:

```php
public function searchCity(Request $request)
{
    $country = Country::with('states.cities')->find(231);

    $query = $request->input('query');

    if ($country) {
        $cities = $country->states
            ->flatMap->cities
            ->pluck('name')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->toArray();

        return $cities;
    } else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Country not found'], 404);
    }
}
```

Also consider implementing lazy loading for the results. Display a few initial results and load more as the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to suggest taking the approach of letting the backend do more of the work, as 9uifranco suggests.

Some initial thoughts and pointers;

- The browser becoming inactive could be because of the code in `startAutocomplete`. While this code can probably be optimized, doing the work on the frontend will probably hurt users with slower devices.
- If possible, I would suggest linking cities directly to countries. Not every country has states and it will make your query easier and faster.
- When autocompleting, you probably don't always need to display all options.
- You might not want to start suggesting when less than 3 chars are typed. Throttle and debounce are also interesting topics to look into.
- In case you want an autocomplete and not a search, you can replace `'%' . $query . '%'` with `$query . '%'` (removing the first %). Add an index to your database on name, and it will be much quicker.

As for the backend query, you can limit cities in the query. No need to map.

```php
return City::query()
  ->where('country_id', 231)
  ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
  ->limit(10)
  ->pluck('name');
```

If you still need states it can be something like

```php
return City::query()
  ->whereHas('state', function ($builder) {
    $builder->where('country_id', 321);
  })
  ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
  ->limit(10)
  ->pluck('name');
```

Comment: I think without map and using the query directly is even better for performance, and that's what the OP is looking for. Nice.